# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When i try to play music on channel, and use command to join and play i got error saying:
`connection.subscribe(player) ReferenceError: connection is not defined` The bot joins voicechat but error comes when it tries to play a song. My version of discord.js is 13.7.0. Probably i just define connection in wrong place but i don't know where exactly. I will be grateful for any help.

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, VoiceConnectionStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const message = require('../events/guild/message');

const queue = new Map();
// queue (message.guild.id, queue_constructor object { voice channel, text channel, connection, song[]});
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'],
    description: 'Advanced music bot',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {

        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have permission to do that');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have permission to do that');

        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        if (cmd === 'play') {
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument');
            let song = {};

            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_title.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {
                //If the video is not a URL then use keywords to find that video.
                const video_finder = async (query) => {
                    const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video) {
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                    message.channel.send('Error finding your video');
                }
            }

            if (!server_queue) {

                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }

                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);

                try {
                    const connection = await joinVoiceChannel({
                        channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
                        guildId: message.guild.id,
                        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
                    })
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send('There was an error connecting');
                    throw err;
                }
            } else {
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(`<:seelio:811951350660595772> **${song.title}** added to queue`);
            }
        }
        else if (cmd === 'skip') skip_song(message, server_queue);
        else if (cmd === 'stop') stop_song(message, server_queue);

    }
}

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });

    const resource = createAudioResource(stream);
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    connection.subscribe(player)
    player.play(resource)
    .on('idle', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
await song_queue.text_channel.send(` Now Playing **${song.title}**`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet in question:

```js
const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });

    const resource = createAudioResource(stream);
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    connection.subscribe(player)
    player.play(resource)
    .on('idle', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
await song_queue.text_channel.send(` Now Playing **${song.title}**`)
}
```

`connection` was defined in an earlier part of your code and the variable does not exist in the current scope. One thing you could do to fix this is create a global variable called `connection` and assign a value to it.

Comment: So i have to put `const connection = await joinVoiceChannel({
                        channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
                        guildId: message.guild.id,
                        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
                    })` 
before module export?

Comment: You would change `const` to `let` as it will no longer be constant and move the variable declaration to the top of the file. Later, in the `try` block, assign the connection variable the return value of your `joinVoiceChannel` function.